# Earth Latitude & Longitude to Latitude & Longitude on a 3D sphere

Tags: geolocation, geometry

I have never done this sort of thing before,but what I am doing is making a 3D sphere (which has earth like texture) like shape where I want to plot locations onto it using the latitude and longitude from google maps of specific locations.Now I am wondering , my sphere radius is obviously smaller than earths radius, would this still effect the position of the latitude and longitude values to xyz given the following formula:

```
tx = radiusOfSphere * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude);
ty = radiusOfSphere * -sin(latitude);
tz = radiusOfSphere * cos(latitude) * sin(longitude);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- tx^2 + ty^2 + tz^2 = radius^2 & math = radius^2, so you are on your sphere.
- if latitude=0, then ty = 0, so you are on a circle parallel to the equator.
- if longitude=0, then tz = 0 so you are on the a meridian.

Just check that you are in *xyz* not *xzy* or *zyx*, and that North is x>0 and East y>0, or whatever signs are compatible with point of view of your 3D rendering soft.

Comment: Ok,well I am using processing which is a java library.So if I use 6371 as earths radius,would I be able to somehow rescale/extract the new longitude and latitude values if my sphere is of radius 250.

Comment: Best way is to try. I remember a day spend in changing the sing of y (which was a z in the soft) before to realize that I was in fact plotting point inside the sphere.

Comment: Hmm,tried changing the x,y,z around to see what happens,get really weird results,not what I was expecting. :/

Comment: Best way is to try. I remember a day spend in changing the sing of y (which was a z in the soft) before to realize that I was in fact plotting point inside the sphere -- Try London, Paris, Boston, New York, Washington and Melbourne to see if you agree with Processing's space representation.