# How can I apply coordinates to a 3D earth model in xcode's scenekit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I made a 3D earth model in scenekit and I want to put stuff on this model based on longitude and latitude and don't know where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to SO Paul. The question is beyond answerable here it is too broad. It is not a simple task to map real life coordinates to a custom 3D model.

Comment: @Sneak im trying to make an iss  (international space station) tracker with a 3D earth model that shows the position of the iss based on this API: http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json

Comment: You need to do alot of calculations and map the numbers to your custom model. it takes some work and some great math. Check out these thread I found for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211776/earth-latitude-longitude-to-latitude-longitude-on-a-3d-sphere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473852/convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-point-in-3d-space http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511988/rendering-dots-on-a-globe-with-correct-longitude-and-latitude-in-opengl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674149/3d-coordinates-on-a-sphere-to-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: If you google a bit you might get more pointers. If you run into a specific problem , you should create an answer with the specific problem, for now, it is off-topic. Good luck

Comment: @Sneak thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to go into complex math to do this. All you need to do is add two extra helper nodes.

Lets assume the Earth is represented by `earthNode` with its geometry (a sphere) at the centre of the node and with a radius of 100 points.

Add a child node to it with the same centre called `longtudeHandle`, without any geometry.

Now add another child node to the first one `latitudeHandle`, without any geometry.

Then you add the space station node `stationNode` as a child to `latitudeHandleNode`, but **not** in the centre. Offset it along the X axis by, say, 105 points to place it 5 points above "the Equator".

```
SCNNode * longtudeHandle = [SCNNode node];
[earthNode addChildNode:longtudeHandle];

SCNNode * latitudeHandle = [SCNNode node];
[longtudeHandle addChildNode:latitudeHandle];    

stationNode.position = SCNVector3Make(105, 0, 0);
[latitudeHandle addChildNode:stationNode];
```

You should end up with the following node graph in your scene

```
earthNode
  |
  |--------longitudeHandle
              |
              |----------latitudeHandle
                            |
                            |-----------stationNode
```

As a result you have 4 nested coordinate systems and every node 3D rotation is set according to its parent node coordinate system.

You can then manipulate the long/lat position of your Station using

- `longitudeHanlde.eulerAngles` **Y component** for longitude angle in radians
- `latitudeHanlde.eulerAngles` **Z component** for latitude angle in radians

which should look like

```
longitudeHandle.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, LONGITUDE, 0);
latitudeHanlde.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, LATITUDE);
```

An additional benefit of using these nested helper nodes is that the Station will always be perpendicular to it's parent's X axis and respectively the planet surface, while if you use complex math to position it in orbit and want to achieve the same effect it becomes even more complex.

---

Alternatively, you should be able to do the same with only one helper (positioning) node and whichever "rotational" property you are familiar with to orient it in 3D space

```
.euler​Angles  // SCNVector3
.rotation     // SCNVector4
.orientation  // SCNQuaternion
.transform    // SCNMatrix4, includes position and scale
```

but this will require some math and/or use of matrices or quaternions (which I've not spent time to learn yet).

Comment: Forgot to mention: radians = degrees * PI / 180

Comment: Good explanation, upvoted, but out of interest, how do you come to the conclusion that no complex map is required for this? The earth isnt a perfect sphere, and mapping long/lat on a perfect sphered 3D model without any math (as mentioned here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674149/3d-coordinates-on-a-sphere-to-latitude-and-longitude) , will not show the exact position of the object, but rather an estimate, or did I miss out on something?